# How to use "volver", "resultar" or "llegar" to say the same thing

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I can say

> **Resultó ser** un trabajo muy duro.
>  *It turned out to be a hard job*.

But, can I say ***volvió a ser*** or ***llegar a ser*** to mean the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

To say "it turned out to be a very hard job", the best choice in Spanish is to say:

- Resultó ser un trabajo muy duro (difícil).

"Llegó a ser un trabajo muy duro" suggests a process whereby the job **gradually** became hard.

"Resultó" is, like "turned out", indicative of an unexpected result: something apparently, or initially easy, turned out to be difficult.

We could also say, with a similar meaning:

- Terminó siendo un trabajo muy duro (It ended up being a very hard job).

As regards "volver", you can use the pronominal form "volverse" to mean "become":

- Se volvió un trabajo muy duro.

"Volverse" is similar to "llegar a ser" as a verb of process.

"Volver a ser" means something completely different:

- Volvió a ser un trabajo muy duro (It was a very hard job **again**).